# Why is there a difference executing functions inside a variable vs executing a function directly?

Tags: javascript

Why is it that when I execute the function directly - both lines " didn't skip" and "skipped" get printed to the console, whereas when I store the function in a variable and execute it, the full function is not executed, and I only get the return function?

For example: bad()() will return both console.log messages, and good() will only return the second one.

```js
function bad() {
  console.log('didn\'t skip')
  return function() {
    console.log('skipped')
  }
}


var good = bad()


good() // in theory shouldn't this be the same as the execution below?
bad()()
```

Comment: looks fine to me....I edited your questions so we can run it.  I see two `didn't skip` and two `skipped` messages in the log. SO you will get the first log when you run `var good = bad()` and you get the second one when you run `good()`

Comment: Because `bad()` will execute the first `console.log` then return a function. Invoking the second function executes the second `console.log()`

Comment: Well good will only run the second one, as you have already run bad..  IOW: `var good = bad(); //bad has been run here already`

Answer (score 0):

The `didn't skip` line runs whenever the `bad` function is run. First it runs on this line:

```
var good = bad()
```

then when you do

```
good()
```

it only runs the `skipped` line, since the `bad` function, which contains the `didn't skip` line, is not run.

```
bad()()
```

runs both. It might help to see what's going on to add some more logging between the lines:

```js
    function bad(){
        console.log('didn\'t skip')
        return function(){
            console.log('skipped')
        }
    }

console.log('assigning')
    var good = bad()
console.log('done assigning')

console.log('running good')
good() // in theory shouldn't this be the same as the execution below?
console.log('running bad')
bad()()
```

Answer (score 0):

the first console log gets printed when you assign the good variable

```
var good = bad()
```

that code got executed and now, what is stored in the good variable is the function that got returned

so, it's not the same as the execution bad()()

Comment: so when functions are stored in variables, and those functions get executed again by those variables, the full function isn't executed? Only what is stored in the return function?

Comment: yeah, exactly but you should read about closures as well, it will help you understand [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you are calling `good()` good is a function of `console.log("skipped")`. The `console.log(" didn't skip")` part happened when you did `var good = bad()`.

Its difficult to explain but the output is definitly correct.

Answer (score 0):

When you asign `var good = bad()` the function gets executed , console logs the `didn't skip` and also returns the anonymous function that has `console.log('skipped')`. This function is assigned to the `good` variable.

So now, `good()` is a function equal to the anonymous function returned by `bad()`.

So calling `good()` will `console.log('skipped')`
Then calling `bad()` will ( obviously ) console.log both

So the events are like this

var assignment -> didn't skip
good() call -> skipped
bad() call - > didn't skip, skipped

```js
function bad() {
  console.log('didn\'t skip')
  return function() {
    console.log('skipped')
  }
}


var good = bad() // console logs didn't skip


good() // console logs skipped

bad()() // console logs didn't skip and skipped
```

Comment: @AndrewTang Glad i could help. If this answer solved your question, please rate and accept it. Thanks :d